# i am new with sweetalert, could someone help me on how to use this package in laravel?

Tags: laravel, sweetalert

I found this [link](https://github.com/uxweb/sweet-alert#the-view) describing how to use sweet-alert in laravel.

**Step 1**

require the package using composer - I successfully downloaded the package

**step 2**

Usage - Imported the `UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlert` in my controller.

```
public function index()
{
    $departments = Department::all();

    SweetAlert::message('Robots are working!');
    return view('department.index')->with('departments', $departments);
}
```

The problem is when i reload `department.index` view, sweet-alert does not work!

Could someone help me with this? Either to solve this issue or give a suggestion to any other valid way to use sweet-alert?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add sweet-alert to front-end?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Include this in your blade layout -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    @include('sweet::alert')
  </body>
</html>
```